# Display URL entered in v-model within a HTML block

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2, pre, v-model

I am trying to create a code snippet builder in Vue.

When I enter a URL into a text box, I want the URL to be inserted into an HTML template, which can be copied and pasted into an HTML document. The main issue here is getting the output as raw HTML (like you would see in `<pre>` and `<code>` tags in a Medium tutorial).

*Code I've tried ([CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ewjvpb)):*

```html
<div id="app">
  <!--myurl:{{ myUrl }}-->
  'Purchase Link <br><a href="' + myURL + '">' + myURL + "</a>"

  <child v-model="myUrl" />
</div>
```

```js
const Child = {
  name: 'Child',
  template: `
    <div class="input">
      <input :value="value" @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)">
    </div>`,
  props: {
    value: String
  }
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    Child
  },
  data () {
    return {
      myUrl: ''
    }
  }
})
```

*Desired outcome:*

```html
<a href="https://amazon.com">amazon.com</a>
```

Previously using AWS SES and Node, I inserted a variable into a code block as `${myURL}`. Not sure whether this approach is compatible with Vue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell this is what you're asking for:

```js
const Child = {
  name: 'Child',
  template: `
    <div class="input">
      <input :value="value" @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)">
    </div>
  `,
  props: {
    value: String
  }
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  
  components: {
    Child
  },
  
  data () {
    return {
      myUrl: ''
    }
  },
  
  computed: {    
    shortUrl () {
      return this.myUrl.replace(/^https?:\/\//, '')
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <child v-model="myUrl"></child>
  <template v-if="myUrl">
    Purchase Link <br>
    <code>&lt;a href="{{ myUrl }}"&gt;{{ shortUrl }}&lt;/a&gt;</code>
  </template>
</div>
```

Trying to normalize URLs is pretty tricky once you start taking relative paths into account so I've kept this pretty basic. It'll just strip off the `http://` or `https://` from the text shown inside the tag, leaving the `href` exactly as typed.

Answer (score 2):

You should use v-bind to bind data to href

```
<div id="app">
  Purchase Link <br><a :href="myUrl"> {{ myUrl }} </a>
  <child v-model="myUrl" />
</div>
```

Demo on [codepen](https://codepen.io/ittus/pen/JQBJxV)

Comment: Thanks, that fixes it a bit more. But I need to output the raw HTML code showing the actual URL rather than an expression. Whether that is wrapped in <pre> tags or encoded... See this forked CodePen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JQBymX

Answer (score 1):

Use a computed property that returns the desired HTML, and then print it in the app `div`. There, you could also add an `http/s` prefix if needed:

```js
computed: {
  fixUrl() {
    return `<a href="${this.myUrl}">`
  }
}
```

[codepen demo](https://codepen.io/eli_chen/pen/jjpYQX)

Comment: Hi, Doesn't display the full HTML that would be embeddable on a webpage and ideally only needs to be shown when the URL is added. Rather than part showing on say amazon.co